# How to get Old signing key back in react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, apk, android-app-bundle

[image]Mistakenly I deleted the old signed key of my app. Now, if I'm trying to upload my bundle on google play console then I'm getting this error :

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your app bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again
```

Comment: unfortunately its not possible. you have to create new one.

Comment: So, what do I have to do in order to resolve this issue? Please help me with this.

Comment: have you generated your signing key using Google Play?

Comment: No, I have generated a key using expo while configuring it.

Comment: Is there no possibility to get back the signing key even if I'm using Git to manage my project?

Comment: If you have git track in commits you can find it easily

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain Please help me with that

Comment: Where have you stored your key earlier?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain I didn't store the key anywhere. Actually, the expo was taking too long time to build so I have created a new account. And when Ive build the bundle it asked "Do you want to generate a new key", I mistakenly typed "Y". So, this is the whole story behind this issue.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain In the above image you can see that I have that Old signing key. So, is there any method by which we can update the signing key in the code itself? If yes then please let me know the method